# I can't get type definitions right

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a simple function, that does the following: it takes a tuple in the following format (Int, a) and if the first element is 1 (ex: (1, a)) then it returns a, else it returns a tuple. This should be based on the CounterElem data type.

Here's my code:

```
data CounterElem a = Single a | Tuple (Int, a)

p11helper :: CounterElem c => (a, b) -> c
p11helper (1, x) = x
p11helper (y, x) = (y, x)
```

Upon compilation, I get a bunch of "Coldn't match expected type..." errors. I presue it's a beginner mistake, but since I'm a beginner... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There a re a couple things wrong here:

1. => is used for typeclass restrictions
2. a should be Int, you already know that
3. you have to return correct types (so wrap final values in constructors Single and Tuple)

---

```
data CounterElem a = Single a | Tuple (Int, a)

p11helper :: (Int, a) -> CounterElem a
p11helper (1, x) = Single x
p11helper p = Tuple p
```

Comment: Last time I checked, mixing pattern matching with partial application as you do here wasn't allowed, and you had to write `p11helper p = Tuple p` for the last line.  Has that changed?

Answer (score 1):

`CounterElem` is a data type, not a typeclass, so you can't use `p11helper :: CounterElem c => ...` in your type signature.

You've also got to wrap your results in the appropriate constructors, as follows.

```
p11helper :: (Int, a) -> CounterElem a
p11helper (1, x) = Single x
p11helper t      = Tuple t
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of mistakes in your code, so here's simply a correct one:

```
data CounterElem a = Single a | Tuple (Int, a)

p11helper :: (Int, a) -> CounterElem a
p11helper (1, x) = Single x
p11helper (y, x) = Tuple (y, x)
```